# Android native database organization

Tags: java, android, databases, sql

I am developing an Android native game, but I have problems with Data Storage.
For a better comprehension think it like as i am developing Clash of Clans, but with Native Andorid.

Now imagine I have to store all datas for Buildings, moneys, troups, ecc in my local phone DB.

I read some guides about SQLite for Android, but i don't really like it. It picks always a `Cursor` object and i have to create an "Helper" class for each table so I can convert the Cursor into the object I picked.

My question is: is there a way to do it in a "easier" way but still complete as SQLite?

I learned SugarORM and it is really simple and intuitive, but it has no possibilities for `ID` and a lot of other limitations.

I want a library or anything else that allows you to do like windows phone c#:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath);
return conn.Query<TABLE_NAME>(SQL_QUERY);
//in this way i have a list of TABLE_NAME items without any casting or similar.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it all and the best way is the cursor/helper way. Its much simpler than using any framework.

Just create a helper class to manage all db interactions.

Persisting data is as easy as this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("column1", "some value");
db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
```

And fetching from db is like this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from mytable where column1 = ?", new String[]{"some value"});

c.moveToPosition(-1);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String userId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("userId"));
}
c.close();
```

Thats it, it doesn't get any easier.

You of course can make these queries not in a helper method.

Also make sure to invoke all db writes/fetches not from the UI thread.

You can read more about in my blog posts:
http://tocrva.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-sqlite-made-easy-tutorial.html
http://tocrva.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-sqlite-best-practices-how-to.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly the SQLite management in Android isn't the most intuitive and easy to do

Comment: Once you get into it is very easy!

Comment: Yeah, You are right, the problem is that it's really really long and annoying. That's why I developed a generic handler which does everything for me for any object :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, you got me interested, could you share it?

Comment: Sure, [I posted it in this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/141919/118025)

Comment: it might not be perfect, but at least it works even if not finished. I have to implement relationships and maybe something to implement methods easily

Comment: Hey, i checked it. Cool as a POC, but seems to me you wrote more code for that handler than you would write a straightforward db helper class.

Comment: Yeah I wrote it some time ago, and your answer made me take it back to my editor. I would love to make it really easier and linear. It will take some time I guess, feel free to edit it and, if you want, post an answer-edit to the question. maybe when I'll have the time I will put it on github so everyone can help making something really useful :)